# reverse of group concat in kettle pentaho

Tags: pentaho, kettle, normalize

In Pentaho Kettle I have at some point some data like this
(they are in fact the result of a complex ldap query)

```
x            y
foo          apple , banana , pear
bar          potato , carrot , tomato
```

where `x` and `y` are column of my table and `y` it's a plain string

I want to normalize the table transforming it in

```
x         y
foo       apple
foo       banana
foo       pear
bar       potato
bar       carrot
bar       tomato
```

It is possible to do so? Maybe with a javascript step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "**Split field to rows**" step in PDI. Use the Deliminator as "**,**", it will split the rows to your required output.

Placed a [gist](https://gist.github.com/rishuatgithub/6387d8c1a4a4ebf4e105) in here. You can check the code.